# I am looking to plot a Line Chart (of Temperature vs Timestamp) in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-cloud-iot

I am working on Google Cloud Platform and I am using the IoT related services available there. But, to plot a line chart of `temperature` vs `ts` (timestamp) in *Google Data studio*, with the data from *Google Cloud BigQuery*, I am facing the following issue:

My data:
[image]

What I wanted to plot: (It's done in Google excel sheets):
[image]

What I am getting:
[image]

Basically, in Datastudio I am able to plot, only the average of all data points available. I am not able to plot with respect to "minute axis", other than for a day-wise average plot. Please help me fix this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

this is what i did, it is a workaround but it works in my case

copy timestamp and format it as hh, rename it hr

make another copy of timestamp and format it as mm, rename it as minute

add new calculated field and use this formula
CAST(CONCAT(datetime,hr,minute) AS NUMBER)

[image]

edit : more context

data studio support only YYYMMDDHH , the lowest level of details is day-hour, if you want to show day- hour-minute, you need to create a new calculated field, it has to be string or number ( I prefer number, as I want to do some calculation on the date).

all I am doing is creating a number that look like this 201908121400, and use it in my chart

[image]

edit : 22-Aug-2019, DS support it now, not need for a workaround

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467?utm_source=in-product&utm_medium=feature-panel&utm_campaign=whats-new

Comment: I am glad you took time in answering my question. But can you please explain, what that formula does and how did you arrive at that formula? Also i didn't understand what 'Mw' is... Thanks in advance @Mim

Comment: Sorry Mw is just something i use personally not related to yiur question,  did you tryied the steps

Comment: I understood everything what you are trying to explain. But only thing that's troubling me is "CAST(CONCAT(datetime,hr,minute) AS NUMBER)". I didn't understand what it is and where I should keep this formula. Thanks in advance @Mim

Comment: Go to  source,  then click edit then add new fields,  google calculated fields in data studio

Comment: I tried every way possible. But still I am clueless. It would be nice if you can please provide me step by step guide on how u did this. Maybe a link u used as reference r something like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: @saikumar see my updated reply, now it is supported by DS

Comment: Thanks for your patience and kudos to my luck :) Will try that and update you @Mim